# How to permanently display the placed image

Tags: c#, picturebox

I created a windows form that displays and image as a Logo. I was able to browse and display an image to the `PictureBox` with this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|bmp (*.bmp)|*.bmp|png (*.png)|*.png";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && ofd.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }
```

I want the placed image saved in that `PictureBox` to be displayed every time the `Form` is called. What code do I need to write in order to do that?

Comment: look up `ResourceFile` and how to use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a special kind of pictureBox that shows the logo. Let's call this a LogoBox. If you make this a user control you can use Visual Studio Toolbox to add it to your controls.

In Visual Studio:

- Open the project where the LogoBox is to be used, or put it in a DLL, so it can be used by several executables.
- Menu: Project - Add User Control, Name it LogoBox
- Use the Toolbox to add a PictureBox to the user control.
- Change the Dock style of picture box to DockStyle.Fill
- Use properties to add an event handler for the Load Event, let's call it OnLoad.

Your LogoBox class will need a property to change the image that will be used as a logo. I use the same function as PictureBox.Image, but call it Logo:

```
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public Image Logo
{
    get {return this.pictureBox1.Image;}
    set
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
}
```

This code is not enough: the next time you load this LogoBox you want it to load its last set Logo. The esiest method is to save the last set image in a file, because then you know certain that if the user of your LogoBox deletes the original image after setting it you still have your own saved copy.

- You'll need a filename for the file. User project properties - settings to create a filename.
- Make it a string property with application scope (it will never change)
- Name: LogoFileName
- Value: think of something nice. Logo.Img?

.

```
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public Image Logo
{
    get {return this.pictureBox1.Image;}
    set
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = image;
        image.Save(Properties.Settings.Default.LogoFileName)
    }
}
```

Finally load the image when your LogoBox is loaded:

```
private void OnFormLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var img = Image.FromFile(Properties.Settings.Default.LogoFileName);
    this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Don't use this.Logo = img, because that will save the image again which is a waste of time.

The only thing to do is error handling if the logo file does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

On the load event of the form you can set the image of the picture box.  By going to project settings, Resources tab, you can add an image as a Resource and reference it using the ProjectNamespace.Resources.NameOfResource.

Comment: but what I want to do is when  a user can change the image by a button to be displayed in the `Picturebox` and the image will only be replaced until the user change it from the same button

Comment: When the form loads you can set the picturebox to display the image from the resource file.  If you want to then persist the user's selection you can save the path of their selection in a variable and in the load event use that instead of the path to the resource file if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Then lets have a static thing.
Within your form, implement a static paths for your image..say

```
public string prg_form_image
{
    get { return "myimage.jpg"; }
}

public string prg_image_path
{
    get { return this.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "image\\"; }
}

private string myImage
{
    get
    {
        return File.Exists(prg_image_path + prg_form_image)
            ? prg_image_path + prg_form_image
            : prg_image_path + "default.jpg";
    }
}

public Image img
{
    get { return Image.FromFile(prg_image_path + prg_form_image); }
}

private void SetImage()
{
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetImage();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|bmp (*.bmp)|*.bmp|png (*.png)|*.png";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && ofd.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        if(File.Exists(prg_image_path + prg_form_image))
        {
            File.Delete(prg_image_path + prg_form_image);
        }

        if(!Directory.Exists(prg_image_path)) { Directory.Create(prg_image_path); }
        Image imgIn = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        imgIn.SaveAs(prg_image_path + prg_form_image);

        SetImage();
    }
}
```

Notes : Folder name image should exists along-side your executable program. a default.jpg should also exist inside the folder image.